# jQuery mobile: Back-button not working with angularjs included only

Tags: angularjs, jquery-mobile

I have a quite complex single-page application based on jQuery mobile and I am using angularjs now for some parts. Everything works perfect, only I cannot navigate back with a data-rel="back" button any more. I am not using angularjs for routing.

An example can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/944cb0mp/4/

```
<div ng-app="fooApp">
  <div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
      <h1>My page 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <p>CONTENT {{vara}}</p>
      <input name="a" ng-model="vara" />
      <a data-role="button" href="#page2">Direct link to Page 2</a>
      <a data-role="button" data-rel="back">Back-link</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
      <h1>My page footer PAGE 1</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
      <h1>My page 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <p>CONTENT {{varb}}</p>
      <input name="b" ng-model="varb" />
      <a data-role="button" href="#page1">Direct link to Page 1</a>
      <a data-role="button" data-rel="back">Back-link</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
      <h1>My page footer PAGE 2</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var fooApp = angular.module('fooApp', []);
</script>
```

Clicking on the PAGE 1 / PAGE 2 buttons brings you to the other page. Without angular you can click on the button below and it brings you back to the last page. With angular included, that does not work any more. Any hints? Thanks so much!

Comment: I also tried to configure $locationProvider, did not help... http://jsfiddle.net/944cb0mp/5/

Answer (score 0):

Added this to my code. Any reasons why I should not do this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('[data-rel=back]').click(function () {
        window.history.go(-1);
        return false;
    });
})
```